# What are the historical reasons for excluding input[type='image'] from form.elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Regarding [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) for [form.elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) there is a note on [listed elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed)
"excluding image buttons for historical reasons"

I can't seem to find what the historical reasons are.

Comment: BHO - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752433(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: BHOs can interface with the DOM, which is what this question is about. However, this isn't a BHO-specific question. I can see reasons for including and not including the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for compatibility with the DOM as implemented by Netscape and early versions of IE, aka "DOM level 0", in which image buttons were not considered form elements (despite clearly being `input` elements that the user could interact with) and therefore excluded from most form functionality. See [this Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113197).

In particular, in Netscape 4 their behavior was much more like that of regular image links (`<a href="..."><img src="..."></a>`) than in IE, such as adding a border similar to that of image links and not supporting event handlers at all, although IE had its own share of quirks as well especially when they were used as submit buttons. In general, image buttons have always been a mess, much of which stemmed from being largely underspecified prior to HTML 4 (and, frankly, even then). See [Jukka K. Korpela's](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/imagebutton.html#tech) and [Alan J. Flavell's](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/type-image.html) write-ups on the subject.