# Why an image input button is not considered as a child element of a form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I ran the following code and found a weird problem: the image input button is not treated as a child element form? Could anyone pls tell me why this happens?

```js
window.onload = function(event) {
  formElements = document.forms[0].elements;

  //output 2
  console.log(formElements.length);

  //output only two elements
  for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
    console.log(formElements[i]);
  } 
};
```

```html
<form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
  <button>Submit</button>
  <input type="image" src="http://www.starmarkcabinetry.com/Style%20Library/StarMark/images/right-button-small.png" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HTMLFormElement.elements property returns an
>   HTMLFormControlsCollection (HTML 4 HTMLCollection) of all the form
>   controls contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input
>   elements which have a type attribute of image.

MDN Doc for [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

Specification related to [Listed Items](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-listed)

You can use `children` to get the same.

**I can't find a reason why this is made the way it is, I feel bad for input[type=image] I hope someone who works closely with Web APIS can shed light into some funny reason like what happened with Pluto**

The historical reasons can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503469/what-are-the-historical-reasons-for-excluding-inputtype-image-from-form-elem)

Comment: Pluto is easy to understand ;) It never was a planet, we just called it one since we had no definition for what a planet was.  We were ignorant and lied to school kids for at least 1,000 years and now we're cleaning up the mess.

Comment: The reason for this is answered in a related question, which I've now marked this question as a duplicate of.