# Why does firefox change align="center" to align="middle"?

Tags: html, firefox

I know that `img.align` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) or even obsolete, still ... Firefox is changing the values of my attributes. In particular see example

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
console.log("img.align:", img.align);
```

```html
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar" align="center" >
```

results:

- chrome: `img.align: center`
- firefox: `img.align: middle`

Any idea why firefox changes the value of the attribute? Are there other attribute values firefox changes?

This has implications for code like

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[align=center]")
```

Which fails on Firefox (only) and so would any CSS using the same selector; `img[align=center] { ... }`, for example.

Possibly relevant: [Can I add custom attribute to HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag)

Comment: Worse than that. [It's been obsolete for over a year at least](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)

Comment: Good to know but not relevant to my question

Comment: IMO this is an interesting (?) fact but not a good stackoverflow question. The people here **cannot** know the answer for that unless they are the authors of this feature => opinion based

Comment: Really? It seems like [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safari) the [quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) of [browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) is one of the most common questions on Stack Overflow

Comment: Very few of them ask for the history behind design decisions that were made, though. Most of them are just interested in workarounds. (I was expecting those links to point to individual questions, but the fact that they instead point to question lists is telling.)

Comment: Here's one I answered as well: [What are the historical reasons for excluding input[type='image'\] from form.elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503469/what-are-the-historical-reasons-for-excluding-inputtype-image-from-form-elem) It's a game of chance, either the information is publicly documented somewhere, or it's not and therefore only the people who made the decisions can answer. I do prefer not to concern myself with whether that makes a question on- or off-topic, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea why firefox changes the value of the attribute?

Because `middle` *is* the correct value as defined in [RFC 1866 (HTML 2.0)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#page-35), [HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#img) and [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.7.4), not `center`. The `align` attribute on the `img` element has never had `center` as a possible value, because `center` has historically always referred to horizontal alignment (floating), and you can't float an image at the center of a line. Other implementations at the time, such as IE, *did* allow `center` as a possible value with the same meaning as `middle` (see Stefan's answer), and so my guess is that Firefox is providing interop while still adhering to the standard by aliasing the values.

It's not clear to me why Chrome doesn't do the same. It does seem to treat `center` as `middle` for the purposes of rendering, in any case. But if by rewriting the value Firefox is breaking attribute selectors, I'd consider that a defect (albeit one they probably aren't inclined to fix since the attribute is obsolete).

The real question is why [MDN claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) that the only possible values are `left`, `right`, `justify`, and `center`. The [DOM level 2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-17701901), of course, contains a more accurate description of the `align` attribute, though it doesn't list the possible values since they're already listed in the HTML spec.

Answer (score 1):

the [html specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-align-IMG) does not know of a value *center* for the align attribute for img tags (but for other tags). however, firefox probably recognizes *center* as value (instead of other nonsense) and accepts it as *middle* since firefox and possible other browsers have done this at some point in their life according to this [rather ancient bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192077)